# problem with connecting the Arduino with 12V electric door strike

Tags: arduino

I followed this sketch to wire my arduino with a door strike.
but when I upload the code on it, the arduino did not control the power goes to the door strike. the door strike opens whenever I plug in its power supply, but I don't want this to happen, I want the arduino to control the power that goes to the door strike. I think the error is with my wiring, can you please help me

components:

1- door strike 12V

Voltage: DC12V

Current: 200mA

Fail secure, NO mode (Locked when power is removed)

2- power supply 12V

3- relay 12V

4- transistor
I'm using the one that comes with Arduino Starter Kit
they did not write anything about it
this is what is written on the transistor: "transistor IRF520 YSK AV"

5- resistor 1K ohm

6- 9V battery

this is the sketch

[image]

this is my wiring

[image: 2]

Comment: another image for the wiring http://www.kentrysystem.com/g3.JPG

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You won't get a good response unless you add a schematic diagram of your configuration. Your _Paint_ drawing is not good enough and looks childish. Edit your post, delete the sketch and add in a schematic using the button on the editor toolbar. Include part numbers and component values. Also, put additional information and links in your post rather than commenting on your own post.

Comment: Your schematic is... it needs improvement. Use the circuit tool to make a proper one. That said, you lack any flyback protection diodes on the relay and maybe the strike plate (may be internal). Also are you powering the relay with the 9V battery?

Comment: Does the relay click when you try to switch it? Your "sketch" is not very informative... You should at least mark which wire is what signal/voltage, what pins do the wires go to in the Arduino, on the FET and on the relay etc. Also from your sketch it seems that the Arduino is actually not powered. What value is the resistor, what type is the FET and relay and so on...

Comment: thank you very much, I will edit it now. I could not add more than 2 links because i don't have enough reputations

Comment: We can always edit it in if needed.

Comment: actually it's so hard to draw a schematic, I'm not an electrical engineer, I'm making this project for my senior project of my computer science bachelor degree, can you help me please?

Comment: @AfnanHumdan - Sorry to be blunt, but you need to suck it up and make a decent schematic. As it stands there is no way to tell what is wrong. 1- your drawing is clearly WRONG. It does not show a 9 volt battery. 2 - your drawing is unusable. It does not identify either the relay or the FET, so there is no way to tell if they are connected properly.  Go back and edit your post, and click on the button which shows a diode (seventh from the left) or hit ctrl-m. The more you complain that it's hard and you can't do it, the longer it will take for us to help you.

Comment: Use the schematic editor! It looks like your MOSFET connections are wrong but your pictorial appears to show it in reverse (markings on the back). They still look like they are wrong (gate is virtually never the middle pin!). You should also put a diode across the coils, show the resistor value.. and there may well be other problems..

Comment: I added the schematic. have not found an electric door strike component so I used something else as one

Comment: Senior project for Computer Science and t he y didn't make you take a basic electronics class? Schematics are step one. Anyway, **Your schematic shows the relay wired completely wrong.**. You also shouldn't need the 9V battery. Once I'm on a laptop I'll give you a proper schematic.

Comment: we have studied one chapter of electric circuit in general physics class. I will wait for you, thank you so much

Comment: Also, you need to edit in a the part numbers or link to datasheets. Which fet? Which relay? Which strike plate, or atleast what is its current needs?

Comment: I just edit the post wit the numbers

Comment: Here's how the relay should be connected: http://makezine.com/2009/02/02/connecting-a-relay-to-arduino/  . You act on the solenoid (protecting the driver with a freewheeling diode) to have the contact open or close. Your door latch and door power series should be on the c (common) and n.o. (normally open) contact of the relay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your circuit schematic is a mess and you don't explain why you think a little 9 V battery will energise a 12 V relay or solenoid in the door strike.

First thing is get a 12 V PSU with a current rating >= the sum of the currents required by the relay and the solenoid.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIyFI1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Relay control for solenoid operation.*

**How it works**

- When D8 goes high current will flow through R1 to the base of Q1 turning it on.
- RLY1 will turn on.
- The contact of RLY1 will energise the solenoid.

Make sure you connect the 5 V ground and your 12 V ground.

**Testing**

- Disconnect R1 from D8 and connect it to +5 V. The relay and solenoid should operate.
- Reconnect and you can start testing your code. You should hear the relay click.

The [door strike datasheet](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=s0UneH0bLWbV3lQ7vEfULQ&label=IBE) shows the following data:

[image]

*Figure 2. Coil data.*

This clearly shows that there is a 26 Ω coil and that it will draw 450 mA, presumably, at 12 V (mid 10 - 14 V DC). (I think you have represented the coil with a switch in your diagram.)

The *Circuit Type* row is showing you that the circuit is powered from a normally open contact (as shown in my Figure 1) so it consumes no power when locked. You energise the coil briefly to unlock. Note that if you have a power failure you will be unable to unlock the door with this device.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have this solenoid component, can I still make it works without the solenoid?

Comment: The door lock works by [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid) - an electro-magnet - which is a coil of wire, usually around a ferrous core. I have to assume this as you have not provided any links to the data sheet for the device (or any of the others).

Comment: Look up this please: http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=s0UneH0bLWbV3lQ7vEfULQ&label=IBE&appName=IBE&LEVCOMP_pses=ZGA4F7E792F33DA3C1DD42B42599CE57060FB419E4594772B1C7D26ED6F814D2F0788E4B5D08692C3B64D23C72EB40F0AB2107167CBA3477AB&minisite=10251

Comment: See update above.

Comment: Thank you. In your schematic do you mean that I should plug the Arduino to a wall adapter power supply?

Comment: Yes or use the 5 V power provided by the USB cable from your computer.

Comment: Excuse me, one more thing, my relay has 5 pins, whereas in your schematic it shows only 4, how can I apply this?

Comment: Another thing, so I should not use the diode on the relay?

Comment: Isn't it good practice to put a reverse-biased flyback diode in parallel with `RLY1`?

Comment: I've modified the schematic to include the diode (recommended) and the changeover relay. Again, how can I possibly advise you on how to wire the relay when you haven't provided a datasheet link? There are thousands of different types. You should be able to figure it out by inspecting the relay markings on the case or with the aid of a multimeter. The coil will have a few hundred ohms resistance and the normally closed contact will have zero ohms resistance.

Comment: this is the datasheet for the relay, can this make any difference in the schematic?: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/electromagnetic-relay-power-PCB-relay-HHC66A_592016286.html

Answer (score 0):

@Transistor beat me to it, but I can still improve on that.

The relay is only really useful if you need galvanic isolation between the driver and the load (Arduino and Strike Plate). If you power the relay and the strike plate from the same 12V source, then you just reduced the isolation. Since you are not using an optocoupler or other isolation, I'm assuming it's not really important at all.

In that case, you can ditch the relay. Electronically, the relay and the strike plate are the same thing. **An inductor in the form of a solenoid coil**. Only difference is the current needed to activate each. The relay needs (assumption) about 100 mA to the strike plate current of 450 mA.

Lucky enough, the IRF520 N-Channel Mosfet can handle that easily, with a Voltage Gate to Source of 5V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7NBTc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**I reused the relay symbol, because it literally acts the same.** Coil was set to 26 Ohms, providing a current just above it's stated typical.

Per @Transistor, the Strike Plate has no polarity, indicating it will likely not have an internal diode. So adding one will definitely help. A 1N400x (x = 1 through 7) is okay in a pinch. This is to protect the mosfet AND/OR the relay. If you intend to use the relay, you should put a diode across both the relay coil, and the strike plate.

Comment: this is the datasheet for the relay, can this make any difference in the schematic?: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/electromagnetic-relay-power-PCB-relay-HHC66A_592016286.html

Comment: @Passerby: The coil datasheet extract in my answer shows "Polarity: None" so there won't be a diode in it. OP has the relay already. Question: why 1N4007 and not 1N4001? In reverse bias it will only ever see +12 V.

Comment: @AfnanHumdan not really. The relay only needs 30mA at 12V (0.36 Watts), but that was already assumed. So your good.

Comment: @transistor nothing. my comment wasn't correct

Comment: @Passerby: No problem. Thanks. I'll delete my comment too.